# Disallow everything in directory except subdirectories with certain name using .htaccess or vhost.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost, conf

How can I disallow everything in a directory except any subdirectories that have a certain name using htaccess or even vhost.conf for the site? I have a protected main directory which contains subdirectories. Each of the subdirectories have another child dir named 'thumbs', that I want to allow people access to. In the thumbs folder I have files which all start with 'thumb_' prefix for the filename. So which approach to use, .htaccess FilesMatch or vhost DirectoryMatch? and what would be the code to use? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm understanding this right, you'll only want to allow files named `thumb_*` if they're inside a directory named `thumbs`, which is inside a subdirectory of the protected directory?  It'd be simpler to not enforce the directory being named `thumbs`, since then you'd just need the `<FilesMatch>`.

Sounds like the path is, for example, `/path/to/protected_dir/subdir/thumbs/thumb_1.png`

If that's right, this should enforce the kinds of restrictions that you're looking for - just make sure there aren't other config blocks that might interfere with the permission settings:

```
<Directory /path/to/protected_dir>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
<LocationMatch "^/url/path/to/protected_dir/[^/]+/thumbs/thumb_.*">
  Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
```

If you're not worried about enforcing the exact directory tree structure, this is a lot simpler:

```
<Directory /path/to/protected_dir>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  <FilesMatch "^thumbs_.*">
    Allow from all
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```